# Implementing cdk-nag in tests files

Tags: typescript, testing, aws-cdk

I am currently implementing cdk-nag using Typescript and to implement the pipeline tests, I am getting the error of:

```
Suppression path "/this/construct/path" did not match any resource. This can occur when a resource does not exist or if a suppression is applied before a resource is created.
```

```
 FAIL  test/pipeline.test.ts (78.874 s)
  ● PipelineStack › Check AWS pipeline default

    Suppression path "/this/construct/path" did not match any resource. This can occur when a resource does not exist or if a suppression is applied before a resource is created.

      155 |     pipeline.buildPipeline();
      156 |     // The path suppression will error if you comment out "ExamplePipeline.buildPipeline();""
    > 157 |     NagSuppressions.addResourceSuppressionsByPath(this, '/this/construct/path', [
          |                     ^
      158 |       {
      159 |         id: 'AwsSolutions-IAM5',
      160 |         reason: 'Policy created by CDK to allow cross-account access and CB projects rights',

      at node_modules/cdk-nag/src/nag-suppressions.ts:115:15
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Function.addResourceSuppressionsByPath (node_modules/cdk-nag/src/nag-suppressions.ts:98:15)
      at new PipelineStack (src/pipeline-stack.ts:157:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/pipeline.test.ts:9:27)
```

This is my pipeline.test.ts so far:

```
describe('Check cdk-nag AwsSolutions Pack', () => {
  let pipelineStack: PipelineStack;
  let app: App;
  // In this case we can use beforeAll() over beforeEach() since our tests 
  // do not modify the state of the application 
  beforeAll(() => {
    // GIVEN
    app = new App();
    pipelineStack = new PipelineStack(app, "PipelineStack", {
      env: {
        account: "123456789012",
        region: "us-east-2",
      },
    });
    // WHEN
    Aspects.of(pipelineStack).add(new AwsSolutionsChecks());

    NagSuppressions.addResourceSuppressionsByPath(pipelineStack, '/this/construct/path', [
      {
        id: 'AwsSolutions-IAM5',
        reason: 'Policy created by CDK to allow cross-account access and CB projects rights',
      },
    ]);
  });

  // THEN
  test('No unsuppressed Warnings', () => {
    const warnings = Annotations.fromStack(pipelineStack).findWarning(
      '*',
      Match.stringLikeRegexp('AwsSolutions-.*')
    );
    expect(warnings).toHaveLength(0);
  });

  test('No unsuppressed Errors', () => {
    const errors = Annotations.fromStack(pipelineStack).findError(
      '*',
      Match.stringLikeRegexp('AwsSolutions-.*')
    );
    expect(errors).toHaveLength(0);
  });
});
```

In my pipeline stack for Codepipeline I already added ExamplePipeline.buildPipeline() to force the creation of the pipeline first (see [here](https://github.com/cdklabs/cdk-nag#suppressing-aws-cdk-libpipelines-violations)), but for the tests, how could this be done/implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the stack name with in the suppression.

The stack name in the suppression does not match up with the stack name that is used in the tests (PipelineStack) this would lead to the construct path being different in your test stack.

Changing the suppression path to something like the following to account for varying stack names.

```
`/{this.stackName}/construct/path`
```